# Is TelemetryClient dependency injection required in Worker.cs for Worker service application Insights in c#?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-application-insights

Im trying to add application insights for worker service application, and following this document for the same. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#net-core-worker-service-application
however I dont want to add any custom events so I have not add TelemetryClient in the worker.cs but now this doesn't log any of the requests in the portal.
If I simply inject the TelemetryClient in worker.cs without calling any method for that it starts to log all the events.
Is there any way we can initialize this telemetry client in 'AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService' method.
2nd approch I tried:
I tried to add TelemetryClient by calling following method.

```
var buildprovider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
TelemetryClient? fooService = provider?.GetService<TelemetryClient>();
```

but I do not want to use GetService or call the buildServiceProvider as it might create multiple sington instance. so is there any other way to achieve the same.
Can this be used without having to inject Telemetry client just to get all the default requests and dependency calls.

Comment: Based on my understanding, TelemetryClient should be used only if you want to push custom events and / or custom metrics to Application Insights. You should get automatic instrumentation of your application with no need to inject TelemetryClient anywhere. Have you already tried the approach described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#live-metrics) to see if the automatic instrumentation works ?

Comment: @EnricoMassone  Yes, I dont want to add any custom events, but the dependnecy logs in Application Insights only appear if I inject the TelemetryClient, I tried to get the TelemetryClient service before without any Dependency injection but it appear to be null service it doesn't gets initialized somehow. Here is my current implementation.  and I have used serilog so havnt updated anything for Ilogger ```        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
        {
            ConnectionString = connectionString
        });```

Answer (score 0):

In the `ConfigureServices` method of your `Worker.cs` file or the `Startup.cs` file (depending on your project structure), you can add a custom service that provides access to the `TelemetryClient`. This avoids calling `BuildServiceProvider` multiple times.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add Application Insights telemetry
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"]);

    // Add a custom service to provide access to TelemetryClient
    services.AddSingleton(provider =>
    {
        var telemetryClient = provider.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>();
        return telemetryClient;
    });
}
```

- Below I have inject the `TelemetryClient` through the constructor.

```cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    }

}
```

- Initialize the `TelemetryClient` in the `ConfigureServices` method without injecting it into your worker class, you can manually create and configure the `TelemetryClient`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Manual TelemetryClient configuration
    var telemetryConfiguration = new TelemetryConfiguration
    {
        InstrumentationKey = Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"],
        // Other configuration settings...
    };

    var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);

    // Add Application Insights telemetry
    services.AddSingleton(telemetryClient);
}
```

- This initializes the `TelemetryClient` during the application startup, and you can access it using dependency injection in your worker class.

[image]

Comment: I tried to add TelemetryClient in singleton but it only works if I create an object of the service somehow, so I tried to add it with like -- TelemetryClient? fooService = provider?.GetService<TelemetryClient>(); and then It started showing the dependency calls in App Insights.